# How did I get more than 200 rep in one day?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday, I earned a reputation of 222 (in a single day) despite the fact that the help pages say that the limit is 200. How is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Yesterday, you had 75 points for 5 acceptances. In addition to the 140 points for 14 upvotes and 8 points for 4 edits, you got 223 points. Good job!

Comment: @robjohn Thank you.(Happy to hear that from a moderator).

Comment: See the [reputation FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for more information.

Comment: Earning Mortarboard and Tumbleweed on the same day, a bittersweet achievement. FYI, machine learning is on topic at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), and I suspect your question would have a better chance of being answered if it was migrated there.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Thanks for that info, but my code is working. Perhaps next time...

Comment: No problem. However, the question still sits there to be found by other users who will be pondering how to answer it. If you no longer need an answer, you can either (a) delete question, or [better] (b) post a brief answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: I followed your suggestion (b). Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reputation cap affects only reputation you get from upvotes (and edits). The reputation you get from having your answer accepted, or bounties, is exempt. Getting a lot of answers accepted in a single day can take you far above the 200 point mark, ditto bounties.